# Acid-base related chemistry

Tags: acid-base

What is the function of silica, $\ce{SiO2}$ in the equation 
$$\ce{CaO + SiO2 -> CaSiO3}$$ 
  a) A basic oxide 
  b) A acidic oxide 
  c) A reducing agent 
  d) An oxidising agent

Please explain.

Comment: Please note that the [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) on this site requires you 
to show some personal effort.

Comment: *Consider to answer one...* Way to go @KlausWarzecha! And, I wanna second his request Tanzeel, so I say: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-‎homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and\or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎

Answer (score 1):

*Since this sounds like a [homework question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142), I will not provide a full solution!*

#### Is $\ce{SiO2}$ an oxidizing or reducing agent in the reaction?

Figure out the oxidation state for the $\ce{Ca}$ and $\ce{Si}$ in the starting materials and the product. As a rule of thumb, consider the oxidation state of (-2) for $\ce{O}$. Unless peroxides are concerned, this works well.

> $$\ce{Ca^{(+2)}O + Si^{(+4)}O2 -> Ca^{(+2)}Si^{(+4)}O3}$$
>  Apparently, there is no change - this is not a redox reaction!

#### Is $\ce{SiO2}$ a basic or an acidic oxide?

- How are basic and acidic oxides defined?
- Are there any rules (of thumb) for the oxides of metals and non-metals?

> Metal oxides are usually **basic** oxides. These can be considered anhydrides of the corresponding metal hydroxides, $\ce{CaO}$ is a typical example: $\ce{CaO + H2O -> Ca(OH)2}$
>  What about $\ce{SiO2}$?